# Get max value by executing multiple query using a single statement

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I am new to iphone developing .I have a sql query **"select pubdate from test where rowid in(select max(rowid) from test)"**.When I execute this query i did not get appropriate result.
Source Code:

```
NSString *query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select pubdate from %@ where rowid in(select max(rowid) from %@)",tableName,tableName];
const char *  sql = [query UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt *lastInsVal_statement = nil;
NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString * docsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString * thePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                      @"Training_Project2.sqlite"];
sqlite3_open([thePath UTF8String], &database);
sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &lastInsVal_statement, NULL);
NSString* pubdate;
while(sqlite3_step(lastInsVal_statement)==SQLITE_ROW){
    const char* str = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(lastInsVal_statement, 2);
    pubdate = [NSString stringWithCString:str encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
sqlite3_finalize(lastInsVal_statement);
sqlite3_close(database);
return pubdate;
```

Comment: sqlite3_column_text(lastInsVal_statement, 2); seems to be the problem as you are selecting only one column probably it should be sqlite3_column_text(lastInsVal_statement, 0).

Comment: You could write the query without a subquery as `SELECT pubdate FROM test ORDER BY rowid DESC LIMIT 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
const char* str = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(lastInsVal_statement, 2);
```

Should be changed to this line:

```
const char *str = (const char *)sqlite3_column_text(lastInsVal_statement, 0);
```

`0` means that you want to get the first column you selected in your query!